# Abstract class to implement equality operators

Tags: c#

Lets say I define the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class ValueEquality<T> : IEquatable<T> 
    where T : ValueEquality<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as T);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ValueEquality<T> lhs, object rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
        { 
            return true;
        }
        else if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ValueEquality<T> lhs, object rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return other != null && EqualNoNull(other);
    }

    public abstract override int GetHashCode();

    public abstract bool EqualNoNull(T other);
}
```

And then create a class `C` as follows:

```
public class C : MyEquatable<C>
{
    public override bool EqualsNoNull(C other)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I then have the code:

```
C x1;
C x2;
bool equal = x1 == x2;
```

Will this end up calling the equals method in `C`? Are there any gotchas with this approach?

**Edit:** fixed some issues in code raised by answers.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do infinite loop in:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        T otherT = (T) obj;
        return Equals(this, otherT);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will call `Equals(object obj)` again and again. Right implementation:

```
public abstract class MyEquatable<T> : IEquatable<T>
    where T : MyEquatable<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Equals((MyEquatable<T>)obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(MyEquatable<T> other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as T);
    }


    public static bool operator ==(MyEquatable<T> lhs, object rhs)
    {
        return Equals(lhs, rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyEquatable<T> lhs, object rhs)
    {
        return Equals(lhs, rhs);
    }

    public abstract bool Equals(T other);
    public abstract override int GetHashCode();
}
```

`x1 == x2` will call operator `==` of `MyEquatable`, that will call `Equals(object obj)`. Finally, it calls `Equals(T other)` overridden in `C` class

Comment: If I changed `Equals(this, otherT)` to `Equals(otherT)` would that call the `Equals(T other)` overload correctly?

Comment: @Clinton should be. But you can check

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation which follows what is usually advised in documentation

```
public abstract class MyEquatable<T> : IEquatable<T>
    where T : MyEquatable<T> {

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {

        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null) || obj.GetType() != GetType())
            return false;

        var valueObject = obj as T; //Note the cast

        if (ReferenceEquals(valueObject, null))
            return false;

        return Equals(valueObject); //Calls Equals(T other)
    }

    public abstract bool Equals(T other);
    public abstract override int GetHashCode();

    public static bool operator ==(MyEquatable<T> left, MyEquatable<T> right) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) && ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) || ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return false;

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyEquatable<T> left, MyEquatable<T> right) {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```